# How to namespace a React app so it doesn't use host site styles and javascript

Tags: reactjs

We have a React app which we are trying to run in a page on our website. Both the React app and the website are built using components from a common style guide. The style guide is currently in a state of flux so whilst the website and the app are using the same styles, it is likely that in the future the style guide will change so that the styles between the app and the site may diverge.

In order to prevent future updates to the site styles affecting the styles used in the app, I am wondering if there is a method to namespace the app so that it would not be affected by changes in styles in the host site?

I am also wondering if this could be extended to JavaScript assets. For example, the app and the website may be using the same version of jQuery now, but in the future it could be that the jQuery version used by the host site diverges from that used by the app.

Ultimately I would like to isolate the app from the host page so that is uses its own CSS/JS assets. Is this possible?